# Add objects to array via loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop

I tried to add an object that represents a food item with a method that uses a few loops.
this is the method :

```
public boolean addItem(FoodItem other) 
{
    boolean isAdded = false;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<_stock.length)
    {
        if(_stock[i]!=null)
        {   
            if (_stock[i].equals(other))
            {
                _stock[i].setQuantity(_stock[i].getQuantity()+other.getQuantity());
                System.out.println(_stock[i]+"equals");
                isAdded = true;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else if (_stock[i].getName().equals(other.getName())
                    && _stock[i].getCatalogueNumber()==other.getCatalogueNumber()
                    && _stock[i].getExpiryDate().equals(other.getExpiryDate()) != true)
            {
                for(int x=i ; x<_stock.length; x++)
                {
                    if (_stock[x] == null)
                    {
                        _stock[x] =  new FoodItem(_stock[x-1]);
                        System.out.println(_stock[i]+"x-1");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                _stock[i] = new FoodItem(other);
                System.out.println(_stock[i]+"expiery dates");
                isAdded = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (_stock[i].getName().equals(other.getName())
                    && _stock[i].getCatalogueNumber()==other.getCatalogueNumber()
                    && _stock[i].getProductionDate().equals(other.getProductionDate()) != true)
            {
                for(int x=i ; x<_stock.length; x++)
                {
                    if (_stock[x] == null)
                    {
                        _stock[x] =  new FoodItem(_stock[x-1]);
                        System.out.println(_stock[i]+"x-1");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                _stock[i] = new FoodItem(other);
                System.out.println(_stock[i]+"production dates");
                isAdded = true;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(_stock[i]);
                System.out.println(_stock[i]+"i++");
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _stock[i] = new FoodItem(other);
            System.out.println(_stock[i]+"else");
            isAdded = true;
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isAdded;
}
```

but when i try to add objects i get a weird output, here i call the method:

```
Date t1 = new Date(1,1,2000);
    Date t2 = new Date(1,1,2001);
    Date t3 = new Date(1,1,2002);
    FoodItem f1 = new FoodItem("Milk", 1111, 12, t1, t2, 7, 10, 5);
    FoodItem f2 = new FoodItem("Milk", 1111, 12, t1, t2, 7, 10, 5);
    FoodItem f3 = new FoodItem("PopCorn", 3333, 2, t1, t3, 6, 10, 12);
    Stock s = new Stock();
    s.addItem(f1);
    s.addItem(f2);
    s.addItem(f3);
    System.out.println(s._stock[0]+"added");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(s._stock[1]+"added");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(s._stock[2]+"added");
```

and this is the output:

FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12else
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 24equals
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 24
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 24i++
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 24added

nulladded

nulladded

when i change the added items to only different items

```
    FoodItem f1 = new FoodItem("Milk", 1111, 12, t1, t2, 7, 10, 5);
    FoodItem f2 = new FoodItem("Cola", 1111, 12, t1, t2, 7, 10, 5);
    FoodItem f3 = new FoodItem("PopCorn", 3333, 2, t1, t3, 6, 10, 12);
```

the output is:

FoodItem: Milk    _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12else
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12i++
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12i++
FoodItem: Milk  _catalogueNumber: 1111  _productionDate: 01/01/2000 _expiryDate: 01/01/2001 _quantity: 12added

nulladded

nulladded

what am i doing wrong? it seems it's never really tries to add any other item exept the fist one...

Comment: That is a lot of code for adding an object to an array and apart from the first `if`I don't understand much of it. It is really weird that your are creating new objects inside a method that should add an object. You might want to refactor that method to make it easier to understand, not the least for yourself. Maybe it would also be worth looking into more advanced collection classes like ArrayList or HashMap.

Comment: I must avoid aliasing... this is part of an assignment so I need to check if the food object differs from another object in dates if so I need to add the new object before the old one

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely a lot of issues to work out with this code to make it more readable/efficient, however I believe your immediate issue is due to your usage of the `break` statement. `Break` will exit the loop altogether, I believe what you are looking for is the `continue` statement. This will exit the current iteration, then run through the loop again (assuming the conditional still holds true).